# asterisk dialplan, forward call to gateway/pstn

Tags: asterisk, voip, gateway

i have VoIP infrastructure in company,
end points can dial mobile numbers in this case:

they call 9... they wait for pstn dial ton...after dial-ton they can dial their number.

i do this in this way:

> exten => 9,1,dial(sip/8003)

witch **sip/8003** is a sip account that is connected to FXO gateway and connected to asterisk via sip trunk.

i want to do this:
the end points dial:

> 909121111111

instead of

> 9... after-dialton.... 09121111111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having seen more of your dial plan, typically what you can do is, in an accessible context, a way to dial the whole thing -- and then use a substring to strip out parts of it.

```
exten => _9XXXXXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/8003/${EXTEN:1})
```

The first part of the extension matches a 10-digit number prefixed with a 9: `_9XXXXXXXXXX`. Check out the article on [pattern matching on the Asterisk wiki](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Pattern+Matching)

Next, on our dial application, what we do is dial your sip device, but, we pass it back the dialed extension, but, notice the colon? Like `${EXTEN:1}` That's to strip digits. Namely it strips the first digit. You can learn more about [manipulating variables on the wiki](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Manipulating+Variables+Basics), too.